# Can't scroll to the top of the page in browser mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've noticed that recently, the code I used to scroll to the top of the page isn't working anymore. For what I can tell, the function is called, and can't find a reason on why it won't work. Here's the code in question :

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.location !== this.props.location) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }
}
```

(I'm using a router, so when the path is changed, it calls this)

While looking for this issue on internet, I found that a window.setTimeout could help, but no success. I also tried this :

```
document.body.scrollTop = 0
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0
```

But same issue. What's strange, is that the code in the first snippet is still working on mobile (Android Chrome, IOS Safari, etc...).

I'm a bit lost, and really can't find why it is not working, some help would be really appreciated !

Have a nice day

EDIT : The Chrome version used is 74.0.3729.131

Comment: window.scrollTo(0,0) should work. Most likely it's a problem with your props never fulfilling the if-statement.

Comment: I tried adding a console.log in the if statement, and it is showing into the console

Comment: Try scrolling the div that has been scrolled. Instead of window you use a ref of that div.